# Memoir: center stacked chaptername and chapternum?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, chapters

In the following source document using the `memoir` class, I define my own `chapterstyle` that, among other things, stacks the chapter name ("Chapter" or "Appendix") above its number.

But despite using `\centering` there, the chapter name does *not* get centered. What's wrong?

```
% mychapstyle.tex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{my}{%
\chapterstyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\fontsize{58}{64}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
%
\settoheight{\midchapskip}{\chapnumfont 1}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{48pt}
%
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
\chapnamefont\centering\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\newline}
%
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering \chapnumfont\thechapter%
}
%
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{%
\par\nobreak\vskip \midchapskip%
\centering\rule{0.825\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}%
\newline}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering\chaptitlefont ##1}
}% end makechapterstyle
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{Appendix\space}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{my}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter

\chapter{The First Chapter}
\lipsum[2]\index{lipsum}\index{lipsum!ipsum lorem}

\appendix
\chapter{Short Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A}
\lipsum[3]

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here's the first page of the first chapter:

[image: Chapter name to be centered]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `\newline` in

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
\chapnamefont\centering\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\newline}
```

replace it with `\\` or `\par`:

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
\chapnamefont\centering\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\\}
```

and you will obtain desired result:

[image]